# CSS flex filling 100% of vertical space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is a layout, the scroll is disabled for the parent element and the height is set to 100%.

```
<https://codepen.io/cefiro/pen/LYBjBmm>
```

In order for flex to fill 100% of the vertical space, you need to remove "height: 100%" from the parent tags.
But I can't do this, because scrolling is disabled for the parent elements and enabled in the child with the ".content" class

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKTy.png)

If there is a way around this without changing the HTML layout markup?

```css
html, body, .app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar .logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .logo > span {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
}
.sidebar .menu {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}
.main .top-bar {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}
.main .content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main .content .left-side {
  flex: 0 0 10em;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.main .content .right-side {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: white;
  min-width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo"><span>L</span></div>
        <div class="menu">menu items</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="top-bar">TOP BAR</div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="left-side">
            Left Side Area
          </div>
          <div class="right-side">
            Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't work around the errors and warnings that show up when you are writing your question in the wizard. Instead, read them and follow the suggestions presented.

Comment: @Adam, are you the copyright holder of the code presented here? Because you just changed the license by copying it from code pen to this site. Please do not do that.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I'll ask the author to do it himself.

Comment: HI @cefiro, could you provide a stack snippet of your example rather than linking to codepen. See here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do  There's no guarantee that your codepen will be visible to future users so the value of your question will be lost. If you have any problem with this just drop me a comment.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I copied the compiled CSS code from codepen. Now the snippet is displayed correctly :)

Comment: We might have been both editing your post at the same time. Can you look at this again  and I'll step back. Really sorry about this.

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for? I've changed the height of the content to 100% to fill the container then used overflow-y scroll on the right side to give you the scroll bar for this element only. The min-width:110% on your right side wasn't doing anything other than overflowing your content and adding an x scrollbar so I've removed it. Your content doesn't overflow in to your gray section now.  Marked up css below:

If it's not what you're looking for then pop me a comment and I'll tweak accordingly.

```css
html,
body,
.app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar .logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sidebar .logo>span {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
}

.sidebar .menu {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}

.main .top-bar {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}

.main .content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;   /* added this */
  overflow: auto;
}

.main .content .left-side {
  flex: 0 0 10em;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

.main .content .right-side {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: white;
  /*min-width: 110%;*/
  overflow-y: scroll;   /* added this */
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo"><span>L</span></div>
    <div class="menu">menu items</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="top-bar">TOP BAR</div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left-side">
        Left Side Area
      </div>
      <div class="right-side">
        Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area
        <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right
        Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br
        /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side
        Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't fit. The layout works correctly (except for the height of the ".left-side" & ".right-side" classes). ".right-side" cannot be "overflow-y: scroll", "overflow: auto" already belongs to the ".content" class. That's why I made "min-width: 110%" so that a horizontal scroll would appear, for example.

Comment: So you want the horizontal scroll to appear if the content width is too large for the container? Where do you want both x and y scroll bars to be?

Comment: Scrolling works correctly. The height of the ".left-side" & ".right-side" columns is not displayed correctly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKTy.png

Comment: Ahh.. okay. Gotcha. Looks like you've sorted it yourself. Have an upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution with a small change in the layout

Added the ".content-inner" tag after the ".content" tag

```
.main .content .content-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: fit-content;
}
```

Snippet edited. It is fully working..

```css
html, body, .app {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 90%;
}

.sidebar {
  background: green;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar .logo {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.sidebar .logo > span {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 1em;
}
.sidebar .menu {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
  width: 100%;
}
.main .top-bar {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: pink;
}
.main .content {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.main .content .content-inner {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  height: fit-content;
}
.main .content .left-side {
  flex: 0 0 10em;
  background: orange;
  margin-right: 2em;
}
.main .content .right-side {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: white;
  min-width: 110%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="logo"><span>L</span></div>
        <div class="menu">menu items</div>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="top-bar">TOP BAR</div>
        <div class="content">
          <div class="content-inner">
              <div class="left-side">
                Left Side Area
              </div>
              <div class="right-side">
                Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br /> Right Side Area <br />
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```